# I have done ssl on mmy website, roundabouttech.com. But the

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

I have done ssl on mmy website, roundabouttech.com. But the problem is when I type complete "https://roundabouttech.com" it opens with https. But when i type only "roundabouttech.com" it takes http by default. How I can resolve this problem. my website is in wordpress.

Comment: can you post your htaccess code?

Comment: will it be safe to post it here publicly.

Comment: yes. you can post htaccess code here.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```